# (iphone5+phonegap) number input field : last characters changes to 0

Tags: html, cordova, input, numbers, iphone-5

I am working on phonegap application. I am facing a very weird behavior.

Problem : When I enter more than 15 digits in the input field, all extra digits are replaced with '0' after closing soft input keyboard.

Implementation :
To accept only numbers in the input fields I have used below code :

```
<div class="input_div"><input name="" type="number" placeholder="Credit Card Number" class="input"  onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="cc_number"  /></div>
```

Also used script is as per follows :

```
<SCRIPT language=Javascript>
  //<!--
  function isNumberKey(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

     return true;
  }
  //-->
</SCRIPT>
```

and CSS class used is as per below :

```
.input_div{width:100%; display:block;}
```

Please anybody can help me, why this problem occur only on iPhone5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Use input type 'tel' instead of 'number'

```
<input type="tel" name="numberInput" />
```